# I can't realize cypress code coverage in Debian

Tags: javascript, bash, next.js, debian, cypress

When I realize a code coverage using Cypress in my Virtual Machine (Debian Bullseye) I can't get the results. But, when I clone my project to my Windows machine everything works.
In linux return this code coverage:

[Index.html inside lcov-report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJXXD.png)

[Using terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ5vN.png)

In windows:
[Windows code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsJHN.png)

Before the test also return this message:
ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reboot my VM and everything is back to working

Comment: In that case, instead of answering you should close the question as not reproducible